# Как ожидать определения переменной в js с помощью Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

У меня есть переменная model которая неопределена, как сделать функцию которая продолжала бы выполнение только после определения переменной?

Пример:

```
var model;

defineVar(model);

function defineVar(variable) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // вызывается resolve только когда переменная становится определенной.
  })
}
```

Comment: зачем Promise для решения этой задачи. Достаточно обычного `if/else`

Comment: @Дмытрык, как ты это с `if/else` реализуешь?